# How do I delete vertices and edges in OrientDB?

Tags: graph-theory, orientdb, graph-databases, vertices

I have two different processes that write concurrently in a graph database in OrientDB. They insert vertices and edges, between one of that vertices and all others (more explicit the graph has 5 vertices (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) and 24 edges (6 (v1-v2), 6 (v1-v3), 6 (v1-v4), 6 (v1-v5))).

Later (non concurrently) another process deletes v1, I hoped that this operation deletes all edges but when I called `graph.countEdges()`, it still returns 6.

More rarely, I delete all other vertices and the graph still has 6 edges. I iterate all edges and they exist between v1 and different vertices but v1 and the rest of the vertices have been deleted.

Comment: Hi, Do you use commit in you process? Thx in advance

Comment: @Michela Bonizzi Yes, I do

Comment: Hi @Luis Angel Hernández Acosta which version of orientdb you use? Is the problem still there?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember if that problem was solved, :). Why do you ask me that?